# Fluid separation in Blender

Tags: simulation, blender, fluid

I need to create a simulation in Blender that resembles Moses separating the sea. I cannot find any tutorials for it. It helps if you could tell me how it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a [fluid simulation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/fluid/introduction.html) then you can set one object as an [obstacle](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/fluid/types/obstacle.html) and animate it to part the sea to your liking. You then hide the obstacle object during render.

[image: outliner]

[image: sample fluid sim]